# is this completely wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know I can Google this but I don't want the answer. I just want to know if this code makes sense or if I'm misunderstanding a couple core concepts in programming. I'm trying to make a number guessing game as you can tell

```
import random
num_1 = random.randint(1,6)
num_2 = input(int(1,6))
print ("choose your number")
input()
print (num_1)
if num_1 == num_2
print ("good job")
if num_1 != num_2
print ("try again")
```

Comment: Have you *tested* it? Did it do what you expect? What you need it to? It doesn't appear to be valid syntactically, so there's definitely a bit more work to be done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. There are lots of things wrong with your code. What part specifically are you asking about? Check out [ask] for tips.

Comment: it said syntax error in the num1=num2 field but I have no idea why that's a syntax error

Comment: use an IDE like Pycharm, and use the debugger with step by step execution  to watche xecution flow and variagbles assignations

Comment: @user12206418 `num1=num2` isn't in your code. Double-check that please.

Comment: Conceptually it's but as a real program which must be runnable through computer, it has lots of syntactical issues!

If you want to just check the concept is ok, yes, apparently it is. but if you're checking it would run on machine! No, It does not! because you must be more precise on the way of writing code!

Comment: Indentation is significant in Python.  You don't have any, so even if every statement were correct it still wouldn't work.  P.S. yes, that means it's completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your code has no sense, "if" loops will not work because you should add a ":" at the end of line, and

```py
print ("choose your number")
input()
```

is

```py
input("choose your number")
```

Your code, with sense and working, should be :

```py
import random

num_1 = random.randint(1,6)
num_2 = int(input("choose your number"))

print (num_1)

if num_1 == num_2: #Don't forget semi-colon !!
    print ("good job") #Don't forget indentations !!

if num_1 != num_2: #Don't forget semi-colon !!
    print ("try again") #Don't forget indentations !!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `:` at the end of `if num_1 == num_2:` and `if num_1 != num_2`. Also add indentation to the prints inside the if.